# Spark running on Cassandra fails due to ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition (details inside)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, classnotfoundexception, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using `spark 2.0.0` (local standalone) and `spark-cassandra-connector 2.0.0-M1` with `scala 2.11`. I am working on a project on an IDE and everytime I run spark commands I get

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My build.sbt file

```
ibraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0-M1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0"
```

So essentially it's an error message

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 13, 192.168.0.12): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
```

The thing is if I run the spark shell with the spark-cassandra-connector with

```
$ ./spark-shell --jars /home/Applications/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-2.0.0-M1-22-gab4eda2.jar
```

I can work with spark and cassandra with no error messages in the way.

Any clue on how to troubleshoot this strange incompatibility?

**Edit:**

This is interesting, from the worker node's perspective when I run a program, the connector gives

```
`java.io.InvalidClassException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1517205208424539072, local class serialVersionUID = 6631934706192455668`
```

that's what ultimately gives the ClassNotFound (it doesn't bind because of clash). But the project only ever used `spark and connector 2.0` and `scala 2.11`, there is no version incompatibility anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark just because you build against a library does not mean it will be included on the runtime classpath. If you added in

```
--jars  /home/Applications/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-2.0.0-M1-22-gab4eda2.jar
```

To your spark-submit for your application it would include all of those necessary libraries at runtime and on all of the remote jvms.

So basically what you are seeing is that in the first example none of the connector libraries are on the runtime classpath, in the spark-shell example they are.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I understand what you mean but I've combed the project's settings (and compared them with an existing working one) and nothing seems out of order. Yet the connector is the only thing that won't work (spark alone works fine). I am using IntelliJ. I checked Project Structure...->Module->Dependencies and the both jars are present, albeit with a scope of compile. But from IntelliJ doc, compile scope covers runtime as well. Do you have any hint or inkling as to where the problem might lie?

Comment: Unless you are running the Master in Local mode you will have the problems I outlined above. Even though the application (Spark Driver) class path is correct the executors will not be. Running the master in local mode means everything will be contained within the same JVM. This is what most people use for testing.

Comment: My master is local as well. I am not communicating with an external cluster. I also added the jar I built in spark.executor.extraClassPath in the spark-default.conf file, and it still doesn't get recognized in runtime. Spark shell + (that same) jar connector works, but that's of no use to me for my system. I tried to recreate the project from scratch. The only thing I copied was the code itself. Same error. Could this be some bug between IntelliJ and the new connector?

Comment: If the master isn't in local mode and the jar is fully resolved I've got nothing. It could be an issue with the guava conflict but I don't think that would manifest here.

For a sanity check try just using that class Driver side prior to any parallel work, if that works try reflecting it as well and see if it gets picked up.

Comment: It does. I have a second (older) project that runs on the previous versions of spark and cassandra-connecor, and that works flawlessly. Imported there the new classes of my current project and there were no issues. Now you might think why dont I use the same dependencies again (spark and connector 1.6), I did, but each new project I start gives me InvalidClassException for spark with different serialversionUIDs. I'm starting to think maybe my PC environment is the cause because I have one 2 month old working project and every new one (identical dependencies) throws some error.....

Comment: InvalidClassException means you have multiple verisons on the classpath. Usually this means the local and remote classes have been loaded with different versions, IE Spark 1.6 locally and 2.0 remotely